# Validation of Employee id using regular expression

Tags: regex

I want a regular Expression to validate Employee id. Id's can be Like

ds-1234;

as-4567;

In simple term short form of company name and their id seperated by  '-'  and finally  ';'
 And it should also accept more than one Employee id seperated by ','.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: If you can get away from this design of data storage, do so immediately. Storing multiple pieces of information (Company + EmpId) in a single column is generally considered a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
/^([A-Za-z]{2,}-\d+;)+$/
```

This will accept one or more ids where company's name consists of no less than two characters and company's id is a digital number.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following regex:

```
[a-z]{2}-[0-9]{4};
```

It assumes that the company name is 2 characters and the id is 4 digits.

Comment: ya. Company name is of 2 character and id of 4. i ll try this.Thnks

Answer (score 0):

`And it should also accept more than one Employee id seperated by ','.`

So you can do something like:

```
/^[a-z]{2}-\d{4}(?:,[a-z]{2}-\d{4})*;$/i
```